# check sum of distincts in one column with a distinct sum of another set in the same table

Tags: sql, sum, distinct

I have a table shown as in the image below

---

[image: table image]

---

I need to write a single query from which I have to get the list of fruits whose total quantity is greater than the total quantity of apple.

so the output should be:

```
mango
```

How do I check with sum of distinct of fruits with sum of just apple?
I got the sum of apple part, but i am not able to get this one done.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: Its Oracle SQL Plus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `having clause with sum(quantity) conditio`n, this will give you exactly mango as output!!

```
select fruit_name from (select fruit_name,sum(quantity) from fruits_table group by fruit_name
having sum(quantity) > (select quantity from fruits table where
 fruit_name = 'apple'));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick reply, since I wanted the sum of (quantity) to be taken for apple also, I added sum(quantity) in the second sub-query. It works perfectly then.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause :

```
select fruit_name
from fruit_table
group by fruit_name
having sum(quantity) > (select sum(quantity) from fruit_table where fruit_name = 'apple');
```

Comment: This works perfectly. However is there any possible way to do this with ANY keyword in the query?